# Mirroring an image by Camera and Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, camera

I want to flip my image when I press a button on Fragment. I create a class which extends the Animation class to make a smooth animation of the flip as below.

```
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {
    private int centerX;
    private int centerY;

    private Camera camera = new Camera();

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);

        centerX = width / 2;
        centerY = width / 2;

        setDuration(1000);
        setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();
        camera.rotateY(180 * interpolatedTime);
        camera.getMatrix(matrix);

        // Move to image center before rotation, and move back after rotation.
        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

        camera.restore();
    }
}
```

When I press the button, call the animation as below

```
public void flipImage() {
        FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation();
        flipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        imageView.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
    }
```

When I press the button first time, the image flip correctly(rotate 180 degree), but When i press the button again, the image was not flip back to the original state.

Here is what I want:
[image]

And here is what I got:
[image]

When I press the button again, the rotation was started from the original state, but I want it to start from the result of the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `reverse` member in your class. When `applyTransformation` is called, just switch `reverse` to its inverse and apply a negative rotation of 180.
 [Here are some useful examples.](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.Camera)

```
boolean reverse = false;

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();

    // Rotate forward or backward.
    if (reverse) {
        camera.rotateY(180 * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));

    } else {
        camera.rotateY(180 * interpolatedTime);
    }

    camera.getMatrix(matrix);

    // Move to image center before rotation, and move back after rotation.
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    // Reverse animation.
    reverse = !reverse;

    camera.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not work, `applyTransformation` will be called many times after you click the button, so you will got a very flicker result.

Comment: Sorry, try to move `reverse = !reverse` at your click handler and remove it in `applyTransformation` should work.

Comment: Yes, move `reverse = !reverse` to the caller method works.